# The websokcet api on Polygon about 0x

Tags: 0x

I find only the mainnet has the websockt api, now I want to use the websocket of Polygon, but I can not find it
So, only the mainnet has the websockt api?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, the 0x Websocket API currently only supports mainnet.